# error C2664: cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [14]' to 'char'

Tags: c++, char

New to programming. I'm writing a simple function that prints a message n time, but I keep getting this error C2664: cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [14]' to 'char'. Couldn't wrap my head around it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
void printNTimes(char msg, int n)// I also tried char *msg
{
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {
        cout << msg;
    }
}

int main()
{
   // char word = "Hello";
    printNTimes("Hello, World.", 5);

}
```

Comment: `char* msg` didn't work, because `"Hello, World."` is a literal to which you have no rights of modifying, i.e. you're not allowed to take a non-const pointer to it. You need a `const` qualifier as in Mike's answer.

Answer (score 4):

`char msg` can accept only one character, not strings.

You should use `const std::string& msg` instead.

`const char* msg` should also work.

Also the initialization of the loop `int i = 1` should be `int i = 0` to print the message `n` times.

Answer (score 0):

Only the `const` qualifier is needed before `char`.

```
#include<iostream>
//#include<iomanip>
#include<cstring>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
const int n = 30;
class part
{
private:
    char partname[n];
    int partnumber;
    double cost;
public:
    void setpart(const char pname[], int pnumber, double c)
    {
        strcpy_s(partname, pname);
        partnumber = pnumber;   cost = c;
    }
    void showpart()
    {
        cout << "\n Name : " << partname << "  Number : " << partnumber << " cost : " << cost;
    }
};
int main()
{
    part part1, part2;
    part1.setpart("lever bolt", 3322, 369.25);
    part2.setpart("start lever", 5544, 147.21);
    cout << "\nPart first : ";   part1.showpart();
    cout << "\nPart second : "; part2.showpart();
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```